# Unable to display the value of environment variable

Tags: batch-file

The code is as below

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd/
if exist c:\programdata\intel\pre (
    if exist c:\Locker (
        move c:\Locker c:\programdata\intel
        rename c:\programdata\intel\Locker UI
        attrib c:\programdata\intel\UI +h +s
    ) else (
        echo Enter the password of the locker:- 
        set /p pass1=
        echo %pass1% )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Now when I enter the password as "1234" it displays "echo is off", but when I execute the below code in a separate file, it executes correctly,

```
set /p pass1=
echo %pass1%
```

This behavior of the batch program is just driving me nuts, kindly guide me through.....

Answer (score 1):

Use this with delayed expansion:

```
echo !pass1!
```